# Reset perspective in R Studio?

Tags: rstudio, reset

I'm pretty new to R programming.  I'm using R studio, and all of a sudden it's no longer showing the workspace, it's only showing the console.

This is what it is supposed to look like

[image]

And this is what mine looks like now.

[image]

In Eclipse, whenever the workspace gets out of wack, I can just reset the perspective and everything it back to normal.  I can't figure out how to do that in R Studio.

The default layout seemed to disappear after I restarted my computer.

Comment: Not sure why this got a thumbs down.  I'm not asking anyone to do an assignment or anything.  This could probably be useful info for a lot of people new to R Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Opening a script file should split the windows horizontaly. If that doesn't work, click on the icon on the top-right corner of the RStudio window showing to windows: [image]

This should at least show the console and file panels.

To restore the side panels, move your cursor to the extreme right of the window, until the cross arrows cursor appears ([image]), and drag it to the middle of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this advice didn't work.  When I click the top-right corner of Rstudio, the window switches between console and Rscript.  But the window for workspace and plots are gone.

Comment: Wait a tick, you were right!  At first those 4 arrows weren't working, but they just did now and I was able to adjust the screen to the original setting.   I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 34):

Go to **View** > **Panes** > **Show all panes**

Comment: Thank you, saved my day :-)

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. If you don't see the 4-way arrows when your mouse is on the right side of the window, it means the panes aren't actually there. Selecting "show packages" etc didn't work, but "Show all panes" did.

Comment: Similarly, the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+0`. I probably lost the all panes view by inadvertently hitting some shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

For all panes to be shown, go to View-> Panes and tick show all panes.
Otherwise, **ctrl+Shift+Alt+0** also worked for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try saving an image of your workspace? Below are a couple of links that might help.

[Workspace link 1](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html)

[Workspace link 2](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html)

My computer is set up already in such a way that it automatically loads up the previous workspace I decided to save. A more qualified person would be able to tell you how and why it retrieves the previous saved image instead of a blank one like yours.

Comment: My workspace is messed up now, so I don't know if saving this current workspace is good.  Is there a way to access my old workspace if I didn't save it manually?

Comment: Try opening a new R script and see if some of the workspace returns.

I am inclined to say no. It's just like with any document you work with in Word or Excel: if you don't save the document (for the first time) and close it out, you'll never be able to open the same document again, unless you retype your code.

This link doesn't look good for your situation either. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126224/rstudio-how-to-recover-data-after-crash

Comment: Well, my vectors and dataframes I created are still in the system when I type ls() into the console.  When I exited out, I used to click save.

Answer (score 0):

I also just got stuck for some time with the vertical split of the panes malfunctioning. I was always stuck with just 2 out of 4 panes.

I'm a pretty confident RStudio user and I tried many things like 'show all panes', moving panes around, clicking the 'hide-window', 'enlarge-window' and 'double-window' icons.

In the end I realised that the panes that were minimized didn't actually have the bar with the title. Instead these we only lines of 1 pixel height.

The solution for me was to expand the bottom panes and then hover near the 1 pixel height line at the top. This changed the cursor into the hand-cursor, which allowed me to drag the top window down, and back into view with the other pane.