# Pane layout in R studio : showing fully all four panes fully

Tags: r, rstudio, pane

I am struggling getting my default pane layout I am used to in R studio (Version 1.3.1073) and view -> panes -> show all panes does not work.

The issue is, I can see all pane (source, console, environment and files) like on the image below. But Environment and File pane cannot be opened simultaneously (in red). I always have to expand one, and then the other hides. Clicking on the expand button (in green) just expands the other one but it is not possible to see both panes at the same time.

[image: view of rstudio]

Clicking on the separation bar, I get this symbol [image: symbol for moving] to shift the pane works only for the console and source pane, but not the environment and file pane, nor show all panes command works.

Does anyone know what I can use to set the default in rstudio pane layout (where content of all panels can be seen without expanding), namely looking like this [image]

This sounds like something pretty basic, but I seem to be unable to fix it myself.

Comment: Does `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+0` not work? (shortcut for 'Show All Panes')

Comment: @TTS, no this does does work, as in principle i can see all 4 panels, i just cannot expand them simultaneously.

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution in this thread worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381742/reset-perspective-in-r-studio

Comment: @Nino thanks a lot, to tell you the truth i sorted the problem as it has appeared, suddenly i was able to grab the line that is supposed to be between the two panels and reset it in the middle manually. No idea what happened, and why i was unable to do this before. I understand that this is not very useful.